# How do I stop Angular from loading the .angular.min.js.map file when pulling Angular from a CDN?

Tags: angularjs, cdn

I am working on a website which loads AngularJS from a CDN, and along with Angular it loads a 284KB map file (angular.min.js.map), which I understand is for debugging.

I don't want to debug, this is going into production, and 284KB is a lot! How do I stop this file from loading?

I can't edit the file (CDN), and it doesn't matter what my Google Chrome options are, I can't advise others to change their settings to use the website I am working on.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps

> The developer tools will only load this file if support for source maps is enabled and the developer tools are open.

So any impact will only be felt if someone opens their developers tools, which I suspect is acceptable, as in that case ability to debug it more important than download speed/size.

Answer (score 1):

Within Google Chrome's inspector, have you unticked 'Enable JavaScript source maps' in Settings > General?

I think your dev setup is trying to pull the source map file in regardless, for others without this option ticked in Chrome's inspector it won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't changed any options in Google Chrome on my test machine, so whatever I have is the default, which is going to be the same for most people who are going to be downloading a useless 284KB file on every page refresh.

Comment: Try using http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ to see what's pulled down for anonymous users and see if the map file is in the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the source map files for production.

Only if a user has chrome dev tools or other source map compatible browser tools running will they request and download the source map file/s.